# Difference between Scopes and Apps in Ubuntu touch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, scopes

In the last couple of years I made several apps for Android (Native and with Cordova) and now I want to develop apps for Ubuntu Touch. I am not yet in the possession of a Ubuntu supported phone (I will as soon Bq or Meizu release there phone in Europe). What I have heard is that Scopes makes Ubuntu Touch unique, so my question is:
**What is the difference between Scopes and Apps?**

I have an emulator running but it is too slow to explore the OS' possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/01/ubuntu-phone-bq-photo-scopes-details

"To use a clunky analogy to illustrate the point:

- Apps are like books on a shelf. You take one down, find what you need, put it back. Repeat when needed.
- Scopes are the relevant pages from those books pinned to your noticeboard right when you need them."

The link has more information, hope this helps.